# How to remove inner shadow on firefox mobile

Tags: css, mobile, browser

I'm trying this:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="search"], input[type="password"] {
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: caret;
-moz-appearance: caret;
}
```

It doesn't work... Why?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in mobile Firefox. Either set a background image, or use `background:none;` on your input.